# Python could not convert string to float

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My objective is to plot 3D scatter with data from different files.

I have tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = []
y = []
z = []

readfile = open('axeX.txt', 'r')
file = readfile.read().split('\n')
for plot in file:
    x = plot.split(',')
    x.append(x[0])

....
```

Note: `axeX.txt` contains data like:

```
9.0745818614959717e-01
1.1413983106613159e+01
1.7582545280456543e+00
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Try using `np.genfromtxt` or `np.loadtxt` to read your file.

Comment: how many columns do you have in your .txt file?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: i have 377 lines and 1 column

Answer (score 0):

use float(x[0]) to convert it from string to float

Comment: the same problem:
x.append(float(X[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 0):

You override `x` in each loop:

```
x = []
for plot in file:
    x = plot.split(',')
    x.append(float(x[0]))
```

So you will end up with a list of two element containing the original string and the converted float from the last line in the file:

```
['1.7582545280456543e+00', 1.7582545280456543]
```

no matter how many lines you read.

Try:

```
x = []
for plot in file:
    temp = plot.split(',')
    x.append(float(temp[0]))
```

If you only have one column of numbers, as shown in your question, you can read `x` like this:

```
with open('axeX.txt', 'r')  as fobj:
    x = [float(line) for line in fobj]
```

Now:

```
>>> x
[0.9074581861495972, 11.41398310661316, 1.7582545280456543]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misusing the `x` variable for multiple, different purposes:

```
# here it's initialized - apparently you want to collect a list of numbers
x = []
for plot in file:
    # but here you assign the result of splitting a line of text from
    # your input file. I would use a different variable here
    x = plot.split(',')
    # and now you start appending to it again?
    x.append(x[0])
```

I would try:

```
x = []
for plot in file:
    fields = plot.split(',')
    x.append(float(fields[0]))
```

Comment: x = []

readfile = open('axeX.txt', 'r')
sepfile = readfile.read().split('\n')

for plot in sepfile:
        fields=plot.split(',')
        x.append(float(fields[0]))

the same problem:
  File "convert.py", line 8, in <module>
    x.append(float(fields[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: